# ST3 & LaTex: Loading locally-defined commands for in-line / live-preview of math equations with LaTex

Tags: latex, sublimetext3

I use a lot of locally-defined math-operators & commands in LaTex and these do not seem to be loaded for processing of the live-preview (inline preview of the math *within* ST3).

Is there any way I can add to the packages / commands etc that are included in use for rendering the live previews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add it to the [`preview_math_template_preamble`](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/v3.12.15/LaTeXTools.sublime-settings#L136) setting.

If you want to have it automatically you can try [LaTeXZeta](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaTeXZeta) and use the *LaTeXZeta: Toggle Auto Set Preview Math Template Preamble* command. This parses your current view and sets that setting for you. However if you use this your manually set preamble will be ignored.

This is planed to be done by LaTeXTools, but this may take while [LaTeXTools#977](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/977).

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer: I hope others will also up-vote - appreciate the time you took to link everything & explain so clearly!

Comment: FYI - "LaTeXYZ / LaTeXZeta" only seems to load `\newcommands` but not larger macros (document commands etc).